# Change MapView padding (to avoid being hidden under a bottom sheet)

Tags: android, heremaps-android-sdk, mapview

I'm showing a bottom sheet on top of MapView. I want to push the map center, and apply bottom padding to MapView according to bottom sheet height. Any thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: If you don't want the bottom sheet to overlay the map - which is the point of a bottom sheet - why don't you use a layout structure that will behave as you want by default? Like show the content in sibling container which resizes the map instead of trying to account for padding and the height of the bottom sheet?